# How can I adjust the row height of merged cells using a macro in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a excel sheet, which serves as a questionnaire. To allow extensive answes and adjust the design, I have merged cells. The problem I encounter now is that the row height does not adjust automatically. I have therefore written a short macro to solve this issue. However, this macro only works on single cells and does not work on the merged cells. Therefore, I would like to know how I can solve this. How can I adjust the row height of merged cells using a macro in vba excel?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You just adjust the height of the last row in the merged cell group e.g. if A1:A3 were merged: Rows("3:3").RowHeight = 33

Comment: do you wish to adjust the height of all the merged rows the same amount?  ...  you could also insert rows within the merged rows

Comment: Merged cells are a bad idea(one of the worst features of Excel IMHO). I only suggest that they be done as a finishing touch on a printable report sheet - where no more data will be added or transformed. Why not look into Text Wrap and Row.Autofit instead. You can get your design by setting column widths first and autofitting afterwards with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, it would be helpful if you posted your macro, but I am guessing you're trying to use the `.entirerow.autofit` command? If so, I don't believe this function evaluates a merged cell. **(Someone correct me if I'm wrong!)**

You might want to consider using "Center Across Range" instead of merging cells. Or you might want to create a rule to loop through cells to check character length or if the "enter key" `CHR(10)` was entered, and size based on that. Example:

```
        Sub TestEachCl()
        Dim CL As Range

        'Make sure to include the intersect with usedrange, 
        'otherwise this will take much longer than necessary.
        For Each CL In Intersect(Rows(20), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells

        If InStr(1, CL.Formula, Chr(10)) > 0 Then
        'enter key exists in a cell
        CL.EntireRow.Height = 30
        'probably want to close the loop or have it not do 
        'anything else once it has reached max height, 
        'so it doesn't reduce the size

        End If

        Next CL

        End Sub
```